# Magento how to get input from user for each product

Tags: magento, e-commerce, checkout

I am working on magento. Now In this Each product need to have form which includes Input fields(dropdown list,radio buttons)  where customer will enter their values and that should be stored with that product for checkout and later to print.

Main-thing is each product will have the all the values which user enters should be stored for that product

How can i handle this, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Custom Variants and Options under Product Information (You get this option when yo create a product)

Comment: Now I give you full detail what I am doing.I am working on magento. I have many products on  home page when i click on any one of them then click on order button then a form appears after fill this form click on add to cart.it redirects to 'add to cart' page.There it shows form details which i filled previously and product details. 
Now my question is how to save this form information with product order.and if i remove that product from cart these details should be delete.

Comment: please elaborate your answer as i am new in magento.

Comment: Custom Variants and Options is available when you create a product. See the last option on the bottom left side. Also download this free Magento User Guide from Magento website itself. It will help you learn http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide

Comment: Thank you very much Yogesh Nath. It is very useful for me.
Now,I want to get know how to set it for all products or i have to set it manually for each product.

Comment: another question is if i use drop down menu in custom options then in every product i need to entry drop down values. Is there any another way to fill these values in drop down list.It'll more helpful if these fields add automatically while add new product.

Comment: You should download that PDF and learn from it. You only create drop down for whichever product you want. Fields won't add automatically. You can duplicate the product.

Comment: thanx for your reply but its not enough for me.i have 12 dropdown menus and each has more than 20 option values. It is not easy to add them mannualy every time at add new product. 
If there is another way to do this please tell me.